# Button is set to lowercaer,but in my android phone it shown as capital. android studio

Tags: android

I use android studio. My button's text is set to "New Button“，but in the preview, it was show as "NEW BUTTON". 
My code was shown as following:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was introduced in Lollipop.

To override this behavior add `android:textAllCaps="false"` to your button.